# Performance for join table with string comparison

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, levenshtein-distance, metaphone

I have two large tables and I need to fit them together. Matching should not be a clear comparison. I used trigrams, Levenshtein's formula, but I get very weak performance. Maybe someone can help improve performance. The size of table A is about 200 thousand rows, the size of table B is about 600 thousand rows.

```
   CREATE TABLE TBL_A(NAME VARCHR,SURNAME VARCHAR, BIRTH_DATE DATE, TABLE_B_ID INT4);
   CREATE TABLE TBL_B(ID INT4, NAME VARCHR, SURNAME VARCHAR, BIRTH_DATE DATE);
--variant 1
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.8; 
UPDATE TBL_A A SET TABLE_B_ID = B.ID
FROM TBL_B B
WHERE A.NAME % B.NAME
AND A.SURNAME % B.SURNAME
AND ABS(A.BIRTH_DATE ::DATE - B.BIRTH_DATE ::DATE)<=1 
--variant 2
UPDATE TBL_A A SET TABLE_B_ID = B.ID
FROM TBL_B B
WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME
AND A.SURNAME = B.SURNAME
AND ABS(A.BIRTH_DATE ::DATE - B.BIRTH_DATE ::DATE)<=1   
--variant 3
UPDATE TBL_A A SET TABLE_B_ID = B.ID
FROM TBL_B B
WHERE levenshtein_less_equal (A.NAME ,B.NAME,2)<=2
AND levenshtein_less_equal (A.SURNAME ,B.SURNAME,2)<=2 
AND ABS(A.BIRTH_DATE ::DATE - B.BIRTH_DATE ::DATE)<=1
```

All of these options had very bad performance ( near about 7 hour). I tried creating indexes but didn't get much speed up

```
CREATE INDEX ind_a_name ON TBL_A USING gist(NAME  trm_gist_ops);
CREATE INDEX ind_a_Surname ON TBL_A USING gist(SURNAME  trm_gist_ops);
```

Comment: This looks like a one time thing.  Even if it did take 7 hours, now that it is done, why would it need to be run again?

Comment: I would expect gin_trgm_ops to be much faster here than gist_trgm_ops for the 1st variant.

Comment: it 'll be a regular procedure for different pairs of tables

Comment: Should I create gin index on both table?

Comment: Either should give you a boost, but having I think it on TBL_B seems more natural than having it on TBL_A for this update.

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein distance comparisons cannot be indexed, unfortunately. Each comparison is a function of both input strings.

One usually approaches this sort of problem by using a two stage where clause that eliminates most comparisons, then applying Levenshtein's string-distance function.

Can you design an injective function `f(name)` which yields some sort of signature of the `name`?  It could remove the vowels from the name, for a trivial example. [SOUNDEX()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html#id-1.11.7.24.6) is such a function, but it's really crude and only works properly on North American names. [Metaphone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html#id-1.11.7.24.8) is a similar function. (The guys who dreamed up these functions were all English-speakers.)

If you do that, then you can populate your table with

```
   name, signature_name
```

put a index on `(signature_name, name)`, and use this WHERE filter.

```
 WHERE A.signature_name = B.signature_name
   AND levenshtein_less_equal (A.name,B.name,2)<=2
```

The trick: do most of your comparison work with indexed columns, and only use Levenshtein when you already know you have a close match.

Comment: thx for your reply. Do you have any exp with ts_vectors? Maybe it could be better?

Comment: put a index on (signature_name, name), and use this WHERE filter -- btree ?

Comment: The kind of function I propose will work well with BTREE. But results from that function are only comparable for equality, not for value.  (That is, it makes no sense to say `sig1 >= sig2 - 2` or some such thing.) So another index organization (hash) may work also.

Comment: To inquire about `ts_vector` use, it might be best to ask another question. Please include some sample data and desired results. For what it's worth the `ts_*` functions work best with documents (columns) containing multiple words, not single words.